# NACHOS virtual memory and cache implementation

Tags: java, operating-system, tlb, virtual-address-space, nachos

I am doing NACHOS phase 3 project (Caching and Virtual Memory) in java. I have some confusions in implementing the function given below:

```
/**
 * Restore the state of this process after a context switch. Called by
 * UThread.restoreState()
 */

public void restoreState() {
    // Invalidate all TLB entries;
    for(int i=0; i < Machine.processor().getTLBSize(); i++){
        Lib.debug(dbgVM, "Invalidating TLB on context switch.");
        TranslationEntry entry = Machine.processor().readTLBEntry(i);
        entry.valid = false;
        Machine.processor().writeTLBEntry(i, entry);
    }

    syncPageTable();
}

/**
 * Called when the process is context switched in. Synchs the process
 * pagetable with the global one so that read/writeVirtualMemory calls
 * can proceed as they would normally in the UserProcess class.
 */
private void syncPageTable(){
    for(TranslationEntry e : pageTable){
        TranslationEntry f = vmk.lookupAddress(super.getPid(), e.vpn);
        if(f == null || f.valid == false){
            e.valid = false;
        }else if(f != null){
            f.valid = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, **vmk = (VMKernel)Kernel.kernel;**. I have not understood the **syncPageTable()** function. What is the meant by **TranslationEntry e : pageTable** inside the for clause and what is actually being checked by the if-else block?

Answer (score 0):

```
for( TranslationEntry e : pageTable ) { /* block */ }
```

This is called a 'for each' statement. It iterates over each TranslationEntry in pageTable and executes the statements in the block. The current entry is named "e". Read the javadoc for more details.

To formalize:

```
for( <type> <variable-name> : <name of the container containing <type> entries> ) {}
```

Regarding the statements in the block: the function `lookupAddress()` looks like it returns either a `TranslationEntry` or `null`. You need to check for `null` first, as the second part of the `||` statement is not evaluated, if the first part is true. If you omit this test for `null`, `f.valid` raises an null-pointer exception.

Now: `else if( f != null )`:
your first if-statement is false, if f is null or if f is invalid. To know which case occurred you have to test for the inverse of one. You could also test `if( f.valid == true )` but, as before, this can raise a null-pointer exception. So what this really asks is: `if( f != null && f.valid == true )`.